# mysql date showing as 0000:00:00 after importing from CSV

Tags: mysql, csv, import

i have a large CSVfile which contains the date saved on it by the time format 41354 which is 21/03/2013

it shows up fine on MS excel but only because you can format it to be on date YYYY-mm-dd

however once uploaded to the database it is showing up the date like 0000:00:00 and it gets converted to the normal one only if press on each cell over phpymyadmin

tried to load file using

```
SET date = STR_TO_DATE(@date_conv, '%Y/%m/%d')
```

tried multiple solutions also but with no help.

edit

table as below

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  date date DEFAULT NULL
);
```

and create a new 1.csv file and make 41354 on A1 cell over ms excel , format it to date and you will get 21/03/2013

now upload it to your DB to find that the date is 0000:00:00

any advice ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a new date for this values: plus days (41354) to '1900-01-01'.

For example **(edited)** -

File file.csv:

```
41354
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  date date DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE table1(@var)
  SET date = DATE('1900-01-01') + INTERVAL @var DAY;
```

Output:

SELECT * FROM table1;

```
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2013-03-23 |
+------------+
```

Comment: this is going to return only the value of the day , but month and year are kept the same ? in other words , i am getting 1900-01-22 instead of the correct month and year

Comment: 41354 is the 21/03/2012 , if you change the cell value to general on MS excel , and then to date , this is the correct date not 23

Comment: Please describe the question. Give more details to reproduce the problem: small file example, CREATE TABLE...

Comment: i got a work around but its really stupid, on MS excel make three cells one to get =DAY , =MONTH , =YEAR , and another one =CONCATENATE(cell1,"-",cell2,"-",cell3) thank god it worked will make it home early , but hopefully to find something better than that.